# how to find Login & logout events in mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsnotification

I am fresher for this application development field. I am tried to get notifications during user login & logout events. I have tried with `NSWorkSpaceNotifications`, but it does not working for me.

Can somebody help me please.

```
-(void)logInLogOutNotifications{
    NSNotificationCenter *notCenter;
    notCenter = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];
    [notCenter addObserver:self
                  selector:@selector(observerMethod)
                      name:NSWorkspaceWillPowerOffNotification object:nil]; 
}

-(void)observerMethod:(NSNotification *)senderNotification;{

    NSLog(@"System Logout Notification is called***********************");

}
```

Comment: are you using NSThread for logInLogOutNotifications?

Comment: No.I am just calling it in main.m

Comment: share your main function code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSApplicationMain` Begin the `RunLoop`. You are calling logInLogOutNotifications function from main() function, so you shoud run runloop.  or call logInLogOutNotifications in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

```
-(void)logInLogOutNotifications{
    NSNotificationCenter *notCenter;
    notCenter = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];
    [notCenter addObserver:self
                  selector:@selector(observerMethod)
                      name:NSWorkspaceWillPowerOffNotification object:nil]; 
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
}
```

Comment: Still its not finding notification.And i am facing another issue with [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]; code. If i am adding it then my menuitem is not showing. If we comment this line, then I am able to see menuitem

Comment: Hi Friends.. NSWorkspaceWillPowerOffNotification works fine for me before. But now i have added NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification & NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification notifications to it. Now logout , restart & shutdown is not working. I mean (NSWorkspaceWillPowerOffNotification) observerMethod is not getting called. please  someone help me

Answer (score 2):

Your method takes one argument, so you should change

```
@selector(observerMethod)
```

to

```
@selector(observerMethod:)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're like me and having problems figuring out why in the world you are not getting receiving the `NSWorkspaceWillPowerOffNotification` notification, make sure you are setting yourself as an observer of `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter]` and -NOT- `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`!

I spent the better part of a day trying to debug why I wasn't getting that notification because I didn't read the answer clearly!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know when user resign or become active you just should subscribe to the following notifications:

**Swift 3**

```
    NSWorkspace.shared().notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(sessionResignActive(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NSWorkspaceSessionDidResignActive, object: nil)
    NSWorkspace.shared().notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(sessionBecomeActive(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NSWorkspaceSessionDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
```